# SVN text file comparer aware of the changeset

Tags: subversion, comparison

I need a window software which makes a comparison of 1 text file which is stored in two SVN Branches. The tool should be able to show, in a visual way, which changeset has introduced every modification between the 2 files.

For example if the file on the second branch has 1 line more I want to know if the line was added on the second branch or removed in the first branch.

Do you know anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) has a built in diff tool that you can use or you can install [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) for windows and set that as your [visual diff tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) by setting the `SVN_MERGE` environment variable, within your configuration file or via the TortoiseSVN settings dialogue.

kdiff3 is available as source code or pre-built for Windows & Mac it is free.

Comment: Ditto TortoiseSVN but for comparison I recommend WinMerge http://winmerge.org/